# I need to understand the logic behind short while statements

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, linked-list

As I was solving problems on Linked Lists,

**I write:**
`while head1 != None and head2 != None:`

**and people write:**
`while head1 and head2:`

Both **while statements** do the same job, but I don't really understand how it works!!!

why does the while loop take head != None by default even when I don't mention it?

`**# An example code I was working on**
def mergeLists(head1, head2):

```
head3 = SinglyLinkedListNode(-1)

node = head3

while head1 and head2: **# Here I usually mention != None**
    
    if head1.data < head2.data:
        node.next = head1
        head1 = head1.next
        
    else:
        node.next = head2
        head2 = head2.next
        
    node = node.next
    
if head1: **# Also down here != None, but it works without it and I need to understand why**
    node.next = head1

if head2:
    node.next = head2
    
return head3.next`
```

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/6340496) might help explain the concept of *truthiness*.  Additionally, a `None` test should use the `is` / `is not` object comparison operators, *not* the `==` / `!=` equivalency operators.

Comment: For clarity, this `while head1 and head2:` is the correct approach.